# 'column "id" does not exist' error while trying to associate a Role with a User using rails-authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-authorization

I'm exploring Rails for the first time and trying to add some fairly straightforward role-based security to my test app. Some Googling seemed to indicate [rails-authorization](http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/tree/master) is the way to go for this. I followed the [README](http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/blob/6a71f147658b12883e18736c744b70db82c482d2/README.rdoc) and everything seemed to be going well, but now I'm trying to associate a `User` with a `Role` and it fails. Here's the snippet from my `script/console` session:

```
>> u = User.find(:first)
=> #<User id: 1, login: "cwhit", name: "", email: "cwhitfield@unica.com", crypted_password: "7ac064547fb8992e8e53e936df31657a40f9c5af", salt: "56671492059f8e40eb3d509940944aaba31ebc72", created_at: "2009-03-26 18:06:04", updated_at: "2009-03-26 18:06:04", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil>
>> r = Role.find(:first)
=> #<Role id: 1, name: "ProjectManager", authorizable_type: nil, authorizable_id: nil, created_at: "2009-03-27 11:02:35", updated_at: "2009-03-27 11:02:35">
>> u.has_role r
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: ....546623', '2009-03-27 11:42:16.546623', 5, 1) RETURNING "id"
                                                                   ^
: INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "role_id", "user_id") VALUES('2009-03-27 11:42:16.546623', '2009-03-27 11:42:16.546623', 5, 1) RETURNING "id"
```

Am I just doing something silly, or is this a known issue? I found [essentially the same error](http://groups.google.com/group/rails-authorization-plugin/browse_thread/thread/db2f0f8995bef55a/a31a19c06bff2f18?lnk=gst&q=id+does+not+exist#a31a19c06bff2f18) in a question in the Google Group for the `rails-authorization` plugin, but there was no solution provided.

Here's my basic config:

- OS X
- Rails 2.3.2
- PostgresQL
- Plugins:

  - restful-authentication
  - rails-authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the `composite_primary_keys` gem [(link)](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) and add the following to the RolesUser controller:

```
set_primary_keys :user_id, :role_id
```

Since there is no id field for that table (and there doesn't need to be), the primary key becomes `(user_id, role_id)` which you can add to the database with

```
 ALTER TABLE roles_users ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id);
```

This solved the problem in my case, which seems to be Postgres-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem with models where I was using a primary key other than 'id'.
Turns out I had forgotten to declare it in the model class definition using "set_primary_key".  Perhaps you need to do something like this:

```
class CulpritClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_primary_key :key_field_you_want

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply used two primary key declarations

```
set_primary_key :user_id

set_primary_key :role_id
```

This worked for my purposes but keep in mind that it returns (in the sql at least) the second primary key that you define. In this case it would be the role_id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but on destroy (of roles). I tried the `composite_primary_keys` gem but found that it broke other things in Rails 2.3.4. Specifically, it caused Rails `:belongs_to` association to generate the wrong attributed id in this situation:

```
   belongs_to :inviter, :class_name => 'User'
```

It was generating `user_id` as the attribute name instead of `inviter_id`.

The ultimate solution was to add an id column to roles_users. Since I already had a roles_users table with no surrogate key I had to do this lil migration:

```
  class AddIdToRolesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up

      # create new table the way it should be (_with_ a traditional Rails id column)
      create_table :x_roles_users do |t|
        t.belongs_to :role
        t.belongs_to :user
        t.timestamps
      end

      execute 'insert into x_roles_users (user_id, role_id, created_at, updated_at) select * from roles_users'

      drop_table :roles_users

      rename_table :x_roles_users, :roles_users
    end

    def self.down
      remove_column :roles_user, :id
    end
  end
```

Comment: BTW this problem with `composite_primary_keys` is well-known and a patch is available for two full years. Unfortunately the patch hasn't been rolled into the gem.

http://groups.google.com/group/compositekeys/browse_thread/thread/502e6b0d77cac8c9/682eb7545d01b141